# How to show only part of an image as the background

Tags: css, label, background-image

Hi,

I have this code:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(old) + label {
  background: url("sprites.gif") no-repeat -220px -54px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
}
```

The thing is that the image I am using for the background contains many sprites so I just want to show the one on coordinates 0 -100px. However, since the label width may vary (because of the length of the contained text) it will show also the sprites next to the one I need.

How can I solve this without editing the image? I want to show only 25x25px of the background image. The rest I dont need. Height I can define but width I cant because as I already said, it must fit the text in the label.

Thank you.

```css
    input[type="checkbox"]:not(old) + label {
      background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/../../img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3) no-repeat -220px -54px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 25px;
      padding: 0 0 0 35px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><label>Some randome text</label>
```

Comment: can you provide a link to a prototype

Comment: Snippet added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying the `background` directly on the `label`, create a pseudo element, size it to the dimensions of the image in your sprite and apply your `background` to it instead.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(old)+label{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:25px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(old)+label::before{
    background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/../../img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3) no-repeat -220px -54px;
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><label>Some random text</label>
```

Comment: That was my last resort and I didnt want to use it but seems like its the only way. Thank you.

Comment: If this has answered the question to your satisfaction, please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem**: Don't tightly couple it (don't apply background on label), instead create a new span for that image. This will also help keep your code *clean*

```css
.sprite {
  display: inline-block;
  background:
 url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/../../img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3) no-repeat -225px -50px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><span class="sprite"></span><label>Some randome text</label>
```

Comment: Thank you but if you look at the code of my question you will see I already know about background-position because I am using it. The problem is not that. The problem is that the sprite is only 25px wide and there is more sprites on the left so if the container (in this case label) is wider than 25px then the sprites on the left will show.

Comment: set the height and width as 25px and 25px; decide which portion using X and Y values, done! _Take a look at my edited answer_

Comment: Please read my question again. I cant set the width to 25px because then the text inside the label WONT FIT. Take a look at the snippet I just edited in.

Comment: @CainNuke I've just updated my answer! Lolz you could have posted the code in the beginning...

Comment: Thank you for your time and your elaborate answer but I prefer a CSS only solution.